# Bootstrap: How to vertically align 4 columns followed 3 in between the gaps?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I'm using bootstrap 3 modal,the design I have to do is shown below

[image]

My code is:

```
<div class="row fr-flags">
<?php foreach ($language as $lang): ?>
<div class="col-xs-3">
<div class="row fr-flag">
<a  class ="close-fr-popup" href="<?php echo $lang['link']; ?>">
<img alt="<?php echo $lang['location']; ?>" src="<?php echo $lang['flag']; ?>">
</a>
</div>
<div class="row fr-text">
<a class="dont close-fr-popup" href="<?php echo $lang['link']; ?>">
<?php echo $lang['location']; ?>
</a>
</div>
</div>
<?php endforeach;?>
</div>
```

What I get is 4 by 3 columns but not the vertical alignment I'm after,and I get the text not centered below the flag, basically I'm missing some margins but every time I fix something, something else gets broken or on a different screen size.

Comment: I think you should post also your **css** code to fully understand where is the problem. Also why boostrap 3 and not 4? it has more utilities, anyway it could be accomplish with 3 as well.

Comment: @lisdey89 My css classes are irreverent, if anything they are a failed attempt to align the flags using margins, margins are bad because they behave differently on different screens, so if you eliminate all my classes and start from there, it's better.

Comment: @lisdey89 Why bootstrap 3 and not 4? Well this is an old, 4GB project in production, if I switch to 4, things will break and there's too much code to fix.